# Как настроить консоль heroky?

Tags: python, django, heroku

При попытке соединения:

```js
heroku console
Running console on ⬢ warm-badlands-80224... up, run.4832 (Free)
bash: console: command not found
```

На сайте- 'heroku run console' - 'bash: console: command not found'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В консоли запустить

```js
heroku run bash
```